# Python - How to turn an integer into a list inside of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict containing 2 key-value pairs, one is a list

```
dict_special =
{'money' : 100,
'sweets' : ['bonbons','sherbet', 'toffee','pineapple cube']}
```

I would like to turn the first value into a list also, so I can append items

i.e.

```
dict_special =
{'money' : [100, 250, 400]
'sweets' : ['bonbons','sherbet', 'toffee','pineapple cube']}
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
newlist = [dict_special['money']]
newlist.append(250)
dict_special['money'] = newlist
```

But I feel that there must be a more succinct and Pythonic way to get there.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did this input come from? It might make more sense to build the dict as holding lists of one int instead of ints in the first place, instead of to convert it after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

A more concise way to write this:

```
newlist = [dict_special['money']]
newlist.append(250)
dict_special['money'] = newlist
```

… would be:

```
dict_special['money'] = [dict_special['money'], 250]
```

However, it's worth looking at why you're trying to do this. How did you create the dict in the first place? Maybe you should have been creating it with `[100]` in the first place, instead of `100`. If not, maybe you should have another step for converting the input dictionary (with `100`) into the one you want to use (with `[100]`) generically rather than doing it on the fly here. Maybe you even want to use a "multidict" class instead of using a dict directly.

Without knowing more about your code and your problem, it's hard to say, but trying to make these kinds of changes in an ad-hoc way is usually a sign that something is wrong somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
newList = {key: value if isinstance(value, list) else [value] 
           for key, value in dict_special.items()}
```